# Convert input into string/var and use it in an alert

Tags: javascript, html, input, var

I am using an input and want to covert it into a string/var to print it out in an alert after i click on a button.

I need the input of "Forename:" to add into the button "send" with "onlcick".

The alert is just a debuger. Instead of alert i want to use a function. Using `onclick="printPDF(foreName+' '' ' + da + '.' + mo + '.' + ye + '_' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s + '.pdf');`

```js
function startTime() {
  var today = new Date();
  var da = today.getDate();
  var mo = today.getMonth() + 1;
  var ye = today.getFullYear();
  var h = today.getHours();
  var m = today.getMinutes();
  var s = today.getSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label>Forename:</label>
  <input class="w3-input w3-white" id="some1" type="text" name="some1" value="asd" maxLength="200">
</p>

<button id="snbtn1" type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-green" onclick="alert(' ' + da + '.' + mo + '.' + ye + '_' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s + '.pdf');">send</button>
```

Comment: Show your checkTime function.

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina I added the code. Is this for the input important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
function startTime() {
      var today = new Date();
      var da = today.getDate();
      var mo = today.getMonth()+1;
      var ye = today.getFullYear();
      var h = today.getHours();
      var m = today.getMinutes();
      var s = today.getSeconds();
      m = checkTime(m);
      s = checkTime(s);
      var foreName = document.getElementById('some1').value;

      alert(foreName+' ' + da + '.' + mo + '.' + ye + '_' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s + '.pdf');
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}
</script>
<p>
    <label>Forename:</label>
    <input class="w3-input w3-white" id="some1" type="text" name="some1" value="asd" maxLength="200">
</p>

   <button id="snbtn1" type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-green"  onclick="startTime();">send</button>
```

Comment: The alert is just a debuger. Instead of alert i want to use a function. Using `onclick="printPDF(foreName+' '' ' + da + '.' + mo + '.' + ye + '_' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s + '.pdf');` do not work.

Comment: inside startTime use print PDF startTime() {... printPDF(...);} ...make sure printPDF function script must be imported before use.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your `onclick` code into a function in your javascript code, by getting the button element and adding an event listener to it. In the same way you get the button in your javascript code you can get the input and it's value:

```js
var today = new Date();
var da = today.getDate();
var mo = today.getMonth()+1;
var ye = today.getFullYear();
var h = today.getHours();
var m = today.getMinutes();
var s = today.getSeconds();
//m = checkTime(m);
//s = checkTime(s);

document.getElementById("snbtn1").addEventListener("click", function() { // Get the button and add an onclick event listener to it
  alert(' ' + da + '.' + mo + '.' + ye + '_' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s + '.pdf');
  alert(document.getElementById("some1").value); // Get the input by it's id and alert the value
});
```

```html
<p>
<label>Forename:</label>
<input class="w3-input w3-white" id="some1" type="text" name="some1" value="asd" maxLength="200">
</p>

<button id="snbtn1" type="submit" class="w3-btn w3-green">send</button>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: The alert is just a debuger. Instead of alert i want to use a function. Using `onclick="printPDF(foreName+' '' ' + da + '.' + mo + '.' + ye + '_' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s + '.pdf');` do not work.